# How to reverse System.loadLibrary in Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, loadlibrary

I am writing a JNI program and I want to unload the dll after i hava finished using it.
What can I do for this purpose? I couldn't find a `unloadLibrary()` method in the Javadoc.

Comment: You can "null" the instantiated object to clear up resources, but the DLL will still be loaded.  Why do you need to unload the dll?

Comment: maybe i will use a new dll,so i need unload the dll first?or something  else that i can do for this?

Answer (score 6):

There is no direct way of manually unloading your dll.

Put simply, your dll will be unloaded when the ClassLoader of the Class that loaded your jni-dll is handled by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

JVM will manage unloading library so don't bother yourself :)

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
FreeLibrary(sdl_library);
```